# Can someone help me with this proof?

Tags: induction

Prove that
$$1^2-2^2+3^2...+(-1)^{n-1}n^2=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ whenever $n$ is a positive integer.

I used $2$ as my base case and it worked. Then I plugged in $k$ for $n$. Now I can't figure out how to do the $k+1$ step. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: If you have problems with parity, just do it for the even an odd cases.

Comment: induction on $n$

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a better idea to assume it's true for $n$, then plug in $n+1$ and see what you can do, rather than writing it down for $n$ and then trying to somehow turn it into the $n+1$ case.

So assume it's true for $n$ and write down the sum for $n+1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}k^2$$

The nice things about sums and induction is that the case for $n$ easily breaks away (another reason why writing down the $n+1$ case is usually a better approach):

$$=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}k^2\right)+(-1)^n(n+1)^2=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(-1)^n(n+1)^2$$

Now, the expression you want will have a factor of $(-1)^n$, so factor one of those out and see what happens:

$$=(-1)^{n}\left(-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)^2\right)$$

Now just follow your nose...

Answer (score 0):

$$n=2m(+1)\iff S=\sum_1^nk^2-2\cdot2^2\sum_1^{m}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)}2-4m(m+1).$$